# Is it possible in Crystal Reports to join 2 colums and show the data?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I have 2 database fields with the same data, but the data is coming from 2 different tables.

Here's an example of my data:

```
Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4
 1     A      1     A
 2     B      2     B
 3     C      3     C
 4     D      4     D
 5     E      5     E
```

What i want to achieve:

```
Col 1 Col 2
 1     A
 2     B
 3     C
 4     D
 5     E
 1     A
 2     B 
 3     C
 4     D
 5     E
```

Is this possible with crystal reports?
I am using version 14.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'UNION ALL' Select statement in a new database 'view' (or in Crystal create a 'Command') as the data source for the report:

```
Select A, B from Table1
UNION ALL
Select A, B from Table2
```